# How to access dynamic property by using variable?

Tags: php, properties, eval

See:

```
$class_members = get_class_vars(__CLASS__);

foreach($class_members as $key => $value)
{
    if (strpos($key, '_output') === 0)
    {
        // I want to eval() this
        $code = '$this->' . $key . ' = 0;';
    }
}
```

Assume I want to assign the value `0` to all class members that begin with `_output`. I plan to use `eval`. **Good or bad idea?**

Comment: Do it with [Reflection](http://php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php).

Comment: eval() is never a good idea. And... are you trying to do this from inside a class method? or from somewhere outside the object? If you'r inside, why would you need eval? $this would exist already anyways.

Comment: why not just `$this->$key = 0;`

Comment: Can you please show me a snippet on how to implement what I am trying to do via reflection?

Comment: Looks like this might do it: http://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getdefaultproperties.php but I'm not sure how to do it from within the class. Plus, this only gets me the members. Would I still loop through them like I did in my snippet? Or is there a "reflection" way to do it?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.setstaticpropertyvalue.php

Comment: My members are just `private` and not `static.` Suggestions?

Comment: I think the function should be named `evil()` so people would understand hat it really does :D

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You don't need `eval()` for this.  You can use a variable as in `$this->{$key}`:

```
foreach($class_members as $key => $value)
{
    if (strpos($key, '_output') === 0)
    {
        // Look mom, no eval()!
       $this->{$key} = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: `$this->$key` without curly braces also works. Although the braces do improve readability.

Answer (score 13):

You can just do:

```
$this->{$key} = 0;
```

There are only a few situations where `eval` isn't considered `evil`.

And this isn't one of them :)

Comment: The only situation I can think of is `//eval("");` :D