# How To Parse a Constant in PHP

Tags: php, constants, eval

Is it possible to parse the contents of a constant in PHP?

For example,

```
define('WHO_AM_I', 'My name is $_SESSION['who_am_i'].'); // setup the constant string
echo eval(WHO_AM_I); // something like this -- but the eval() returns an error
```

Please note that I do not know the value of the _SESSION var until I actually use the constant later in the script stream.

Thanks.

**AMENDED WITH REASON FOR WANTING TO DO THIS**

I want to pull "hard coding" out of my script and give the user the ability to configure certain taxonomy in their site. So while I was doing this I also wanted to create a quasi-dynamic constant that I thought I might be able to parse later in the script.

If it can't be done...then it can't be done.

Don't shoot me for asking the question though.

**A FINAL COMMENT TO AVOID ALL THIS CONFUSION**

The purpose of my question has nothing to do with the eval() function. I am actually regretting having put it in there in the first place.

I put the eval() in the question simply to demonstrate to stackoverflow members that I did a bit if prep on my question rather than asking an open ended -- hey give me a solution without having offered any stab at it myself. So please disregard the eval().

All I want to know is can I somehow craft a define() in an way that makes the assigned value parse-able later in my script. That's it, that's all.

**AMENDMENT C**

I know I can do the following although I don't want to do it this way:

```
define('PARSE_ABLE_CONSTANT_PART_A', 'My name is ');
define('PARSE_ABLE_CONSTANT_PART_B', '.');
```

...later down the script road...

```
echo PARSE_ABLE_CONSTANT_PART_A . $_SESSION['who_am_i'] . PARSE_ABLE_CONSTANT_PART_B;
```

I just don't want to do it this way if I can make it slicker using an embedded var in the constant.

Comment: Just don't please. What is it you are actually trying to do? Also you have a syntax error even before that horrid `eval()`.

Comment: What error occurs where you say "eval() returns an error"?

Comment: why do you use eval? What do you wish to accomplish? And `define('WHO_AM_I', 'My name is $_SESSION['who_am_i'].');` will never work it should be: `define('WHO_AM_I', 'My name is '.$_SESSION['who_am_i']);`

Comment: The error is as follows @Vulcan `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /home/abc/public_html/sandbox/eval/index.php(12) : eval()'d code on line 1`

Comment: I only threw in the eval() a a guess to see if I could get the constant to parse @John

Comment: I will amend my question with the reason behind the need to do this.

Comment: Thanks for the down vote. I love getting them when I try to ask a legit question and learn something here at the ego-site

Comment: Just don't please `what` @PeeHaa ?

Comment: Don't use `eval()`, [because it is `evil()`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8137599/508666).

Comment: I only threw it in there real quick to see what would happen. I didn't assume eval() would even be the answer.

Comment: @H.Ferrence What you really want is configuration.  One simple way to do this is to create a config.php file.  In it you can place whatever variables or constants you want.  You then require_once this file.  It's also possible to implement a registry based on the singleton pattern, and make the contents of this object available via a static method call.  See the http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.registry.html as an example.

Comment: I already gave the "config.file". It contains constants. I simply want to add one more constant that contains an embedded variable. Hoping later in the script I can parse it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Constants by definition don't allow you to set it with dynamic content.

Here is a quote from the php manual:

> As the name suggests, that value cannot change during the execution
>   of the script

You can see more by going [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php)

You might be thinking of [magical constants](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php)

Comment: This is incorrect; constants can be defined at runtime using [`define`](http://php.net/define).

Comment: Yes, I am full aware of the scope of the constant @pzirkind. Just asking if there is some clever way of "parsing" a constant...

Comment: @H.Ferrence hmm, interesting. why don't you want to use a regular variable to hold them? trying to better understand

Comment: see my Amendment C @pzirkind

Answer (score 2):

This seems really fishy, as other users have pointed out. You could do something like this if you wanted:

```
define('WHO_AM_I', 'echo \'My name is \'.$_SESSION[\'who_am_i\'];');
eval(WHO_AM_I);
```

This will always just echo the variable. You need to eval an expression afaik.

Just read your edit. I think you would be better suited with an .ini file, or maybe a static class with static properties. Makes it much more flexible, and you avoid the eval. You are talking user-generated content from what I can see - subjecting that to an eval call seems highly insecure.

A quick example of a static class you could use:

```
<?php
class myConstants{
  public static function _($key){
    switch($key){
      case "WHO_AM_I":
        return "My name is ".$_SESSION['who_am_i'];
        break;
      case "OTHER_CONSTANT":
        // does some other evaluation and returns a string
        break;
    }
    throw new Exception("Constant isn't defined");
  }
}
?>
```

Then you can just `echo myConstants::_('WHO_AM_I');`

Comment: I produced [a similar example](http://codepad.org/akcIeekZ).  But regardless, as a rule of thumb, if you think you need to use `eval()`, you don't -- there's almost always a better way.

Comment: I am not sure why you think my question is "fishy" @EsbenTind. I was thinking that I was asking a very, very simply and basic question -- "can you create a constant in such a way that it contains an embedded variable that can be parsed later in the script?" That's all I am asking and looking for.

Comment: Then no. A constant is only parsed when you define it. I thought you had a reason for using eval (i.e. you where changing you session later on, and wanted your constant to reflect the new value). If this is not the case, just do `define('WHO_AM_I', 'My name is '.$session['who_am_i'].'.');`. A class with static properties/methods is also accesible in both global and local scopes. Those can also compile when you call them. Hence why I suggested that solution.